# What kind of entity does the Main Class in Java represent?

Tags: java, class, object, oop, program-entry-point

Whenever we see an introduction to Object Oriented Programming, we commonly come across this explanation, A class is a blueprint of an object, it can be used to represent a real world entity virtually, like for example a vehicle, each entity has certain properties and behavior(in this case let's say properties would be number of wheels, make and model of the car and behavior would be honking, driving, applying brakes etc), which can represented as variables and functions in the class respectively.

Now, when we come across a whole bunch of classes in a project, we can see that there is one particular Main class, in which there are no variables and other methods as such(other than the Main method)but we see objects of other classes being created inside the main function and several other methods being called and executed, other operations being performed.

In this case, what kind of a real world entity is the Main class representing which has no property or behavior? If the whole purpose of introducing classes and objects is to virtualize real world entities then what sort of a class is the main class?

Also, if this Class is not representing any entity as such then why does the Main function have to be inside it? Why Can't the main function be written separately without being included in a Class, with the sole purpose of manipulating with objects of other classes or doing some other stuff?

Comment: You could ask that question for every class that is not designed to be instantiated - `System`, `Math`, etc. At the end of the day, it comes down to the (arguably questionable) design decisions of the language.

Comment: Seems to have some philosophical overtones

Comment: *Why Can't the main function be written separately without being included in a Class* It is possible in a project to have multiple `Main` Methods.  As they are in classes, which Main method you want to call is unambiguous.

Comment: I contest that we keep this question open, or point to duplicate with a more recent answer. Java 21 is going to change the answer to this question ***significantly***, and therefore, we should have the opportunity to answer it with a fresh pair of eyes.

Comment: Plus, the linked duplicate is full of bad and incomplete answers. None of them do a good job of answering this question. If we are going to flag things as duplicate, we should do a better job than this to point to the correct answer.

Comment: Someone notify when this question becomes unduplicated/reopened. I had a nice, detailed answer I was working on that would have addressed this answer for past, present, and future, as well as by addressing some of the mistaken (but understandable) assumptions that many beginners (like OP) have fallen into.

Comment: @davidalayachew - why not add an up-to-date answer in the linked duplicate ?

Comment: @ScaryWombat Ignoring the fact that the question has a whole bunch of terrible answers that would drown out mine, it's also because the question is 7+ years old. The OP for that post has not logged on in over a year, so my answer would be sitting there, unaccepted. If I am going to answer this question, I want to answer it thoroughly, in such a way that the clearly correct answer can sit at the top and be scrutinized while all of the experts are still going through the new questions.

Comment: @ScaryWombat Furthermore, I don't see any great answers to this question that include Java 21. I want to write a super detailed answer such that, any future people that ask this question can get pointed to my answer and they will have a clear, details answer to meet any of their questions.

Comment: @davidalayachew can you please write your answer here in the comment section? I am eager to know your take on this.

Comment: @nick Not in the comments section, but here is a link to StackOverflow Chat. I'll post the answer there. https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/139/java

Answer (score -2):

The main class is the class which will be called when you start your program. So this is the place where you intialialize the classes you will be using and where you call the methods to start your code working.

Comment: This does not answer their question. They are not asking what a "Main class" is, they are trying to understand why it works the way it does, and where it stands relative to the rest of the class structure.